# Variable not auto incrementing Python

Tags: python

I have to classify this list (Lista variable) according to their data type, and the code works as far as I pick a specific [] to classify but the i inside the for and if loops is not augmenting after each loop.

```html
__author__ = 'rodrigocano'

Lista = [55.5,'hola','abc',10,'5','x5',0.25,['A',2,1.5],5,2,5.3,'AEIOU',('perro','gato','pollo'),[1,2,3],1001,['a',1],'mundo','01/10/2015',20080633,'2.5',0.123,(1,2,'A','B')]
lista_clasificable = len(Lista)
def clasificar(lista_clasificable):
    for Lista in range(0,len(lista_clasificable)):
        i = 0
        lista_string = []
        lista_int = []
        lista_float =[]
        lista_tuple = []
        lista_list = [] #duh
        if type(lista_clasificable[i]) is str:
            lista_string.append(lista_clasificable[i])
            i += 1
        elif type(lista_clasificable[i]) is int:
            lista_int.append(lista_clasificable[i])
            i += 1
        elif type(lista_clasificable[i]) is float:
            lista_float.append(lista_clasificable[i])
            i += 1
        elif type(lista_clasificable[i]) is list :
            lista_list.append(lista_clasificable[i])
            i += 1
        elif type(lista_clasificable[i]) is tuple:
            lista_tuple.append(lista_clasificable[i])
            i += 1
    return 'Su Lista contiente los siguientes ints',lista_int,'Sus Strings son:',lista_string,'Sus floats son:',lista_float,'Sus listas son:',lista_list,'Y Sus tuplas son:',lista_tuple

print(clasificar(Lista))
```

Comment: The variable is reassigned each loop. Also the entire loop structure is.. odd.

Comment: It's not merely odd, it is absurd. Separating a heterogeneous list by a handful of types? I can think of no situation where this would be useful (unless the assignment was to do precisely that).

Comment: ... assignment is to precisely do that, first semester cs student.

Comment: If you use a `defaultdict` you can reduce the loop to the following code: `for element in lista_clasificable: categories[str(type(element).__name__)] = element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're resetting i over and over. It is inside your for loop, so for every item, i is first set to 0. You need to put it before your for loop:

```
i=0
for Lista in range(0,len(lista_clasificable)):
    ...
```

See MSW's comment for your 2nd problem. You are also overwriting the master lists each time, I missed that.

This is pretty un-pythonesque though. Instead of getting the length of the list and using this setup where i tracks the index, just do something like:

```
for item in Lista: 
    do something
```

Python can loop through the list directly - you don't need to use indexing.

Comment: Thanks so much, now it skips every item in between the first and last, only classifying those.

Comment: It also nulls out the lista_* on every iteration.

Comment: I don't see immediately why that is happening but your setup here is very un-pythonesque. Instead of getting the length of the list and using this setup where i tracks the index, just do something like:

    for item in Lista:
        do something

Python can loop through the list directly - you don't need to use indexing.

Comment: @AustinC Yeah, changing the variables above the for loop solved it, thanks !

Comment: @RodrigoCano If you have new question please post a new thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting i to zero at every iteration of the for loop. Put the `i=0` above your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner version. I am not explaining it in the hopes that you will learn. Ask questions if you can't puzzle it out with the manual at hand. Sorry if I botched the Spanish.

```
# a little more pythonically and far less repetitious

def classificar(p, types):
    # create a dict of lists such that dict[typename] = []
    lists = dict()
    for t in types:
        lists[t.__name__] = []

    # for all of the elements in p, assign them to a type list
    # if applicable
    for x in p:
        for t in types:
            if type(x) == t:
                lists[t.__name__].append(x)

    return lists            

input = [55.5,'hola','abc',10,'5','x5',0.25,['A',2,1.5],5,2,5.3,'AEIOU',
         ('perro','gato','pollo'), [1,2,3], 1001, ['a', 1],
         'mundo','01/10/2015',20080633,'2.5',0.123,(1,2,'A','B')]
types = [str, int, float, tuple, list]

lists = classificar(input, types)
print('Su lista contiente los siguientes:')
for type in types:
    print('  ', type.__name__, lists[type.__name__])
```